# Compare Date/Time in SQL Server T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We have this format Date/Time stored in a varChar column for each row in our table: 2013-05-26 20:22:07.2894.

How can we use this column in a T_SQL WHERE statement to retrieve the last 1 hour's worth of rows?

We have tried this and it works: WHERE Time_Stamp > '2013-05-26 18:00:00:0000' however we would like to have the T-SQL to work automatically rather than having the date/tie hard coded.

Comment: Why are you storing this as `varchar`?

Comment: This is something I have inherited from the previous chap.

Comment: Have you considered `alter table <t> alter column Time_Stamp datetime`?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a sargable approach (meaning it will use the index):

```
where Time_Stamp > convert(varchar(255), getdate() - 1.0/24, 121)
```

Comment: @Adam . . . Glad I could be of help.

Answer (score 1):

To convert your `VARCHAR` to a `DATETIME`, just use;

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING(myDate, 1, 23), 121);
```

...where myDate is your column name. Once it's converted to a datetime, a comparison with `GETDATE()` is simple.

[A very simple SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/63fad/3).

Answer (score 0):

You could combine `getdate()` with `dateadd()` to subtract 1 hour from the current time:

```
WHERE Time_Stamp > dateadd(hour, -1, getdate())
```

The `varchar` will be converted to `datetime` for the comparison because datetime has [higher precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx).

Comment: `varchar` being converted to a `datetime` is a negative in this case as it makes the `WHERE` unsargable.

Comment: This results in an error: 
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Probably right, but the question doesn't say the `Time_Stamp` column has an index.  Even if it had, SQL Server is unlikely to use an index for a `<` condition unless the index is covering.

Comment: @Andomar - That depends on the tipping point. To retrieve "the last 1 hour's worth of rows" even if the table only has 4 days of data that will still only be about 1% of the table and SQL Server may favour a plan with lookups to scanning the whole thing.

Comment: @MartinSmith: In my experience the tipping point is at 100 rows or more.  In any case, it strikes me as somewhat weird to answer a beginner's question about dates with low-level details of sargeability.

Answer (score 0):

```
Datediff(hour, time_stamp, getdate()) < 1
```

But you are likely making a mistake in storing that timestamp as a varchar. When you store it as a varchar, SQL is going to have to check every candidate row on the table to find the records, and it will have to convert every single value of `timestamp` to a dateline, in order to be able to identify the records you are looking for. Hopefully your query's conditions are such that this will only require checking a handful of records.

But really, there is no reason to store the dates as strings. storing them as datetime takes less space, results in faster queries, and might allows SQL to pick better query plans. hiding the nature of your values from the server only prevents it from helping you out, and causes you to have to worry about what happens when a field value is 'Hello' instead of '2013-05-26 18:00:00:0000' You should store your dates as Datetime, and you should build an appropriate index for it (the details of the index that you need require a lot more information about your system than what you hae provided).